# общая тема для user и root в KDE 5

Tags: linux, themes, kde

Как сделать так что бы при установке темы оформления она применялась ко всем пользователям включая root? Если выбрать тему на черех обычного пользователя и открыть например файловый менеджер то эта тема не применится, так же если установить тему через root ее не будет видно другим пользователям. Я пробовал закинуть папки с темами в локальных папках и в системные, но мне это не помогло.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Не помогло скорее всего из-за `ugo`. А вообще сам в своё время задавался этим вопросом, когда сидел на kde3. Теперь считаю, что различие в оформлении должно быть для разных пользователей, чтобы глаз не замыливался и ты чётко понимал под каким пользователем сейчас правишь\открываешь\создаёшь файлы. Я бы даже рекомендовал раскрасить приветствие консоли в разные цвета. Если интересует - дополню ответ.

**UPD1**. По заявкам трудящихся привожу пример раскраски консоли `bash`. Строки надо добавлять в `$HOME/.bashrc` каждого пользователя.

Для обычного пользователя:

```
PS1='\u@\[\e[0;32m\]\h\[\e[0m\]:\w> '
```

Для root:

```
echo -e '\n\e[1;31mGODMODE ON! \e[0m\n'
PS1='\[\e[1;31m\]\u@\[\e[0;32m\]\h\[\e[1;31m\]:\w#\[\e[0m\] '
```

Для применения изменений нужно перезайти в терминалы.

Откуда я взял абракадабру:

http://xgu.ru/wiki/PS1

**UPD2**.

Вообще, настройки по-умолчанию должны храниться где-то в `/etc`. Для того же bash при создании нового пользователя копируются эталонные файлы из `/etc/skel`. Поищи `/etc/kde`, '/etc/kde5' или типа того.

Comment: Да, я хотел бы узнать ваше мнение по этому вопросу.

Comment: Мб еще подскажите, знакома ли такая ошибка XDG_RUNTIME_DIR not set, defaulting to '/tmp/runtime-root'. Запускаю dolphin через kdesudo, после перезагрузки компа один раз запускается нормально, а потом постояно эта ошибка.

Comment: @Bleser, это лучше ещё 1 вопрос задать.